# How to get the PrintDocumentImageableArea for a given PrintQueue without going through PrintDialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

From MSDN ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552918.aspx)):

> The type PrintDocumentImageableArea
> has no public constructor. Hence, the
> variable documentImageableArea must be
> declared and assigned to Nothing and
> only then passed to the method. This
> method displays a PrintDialog
> requiring input from the user. After
> the user has selected a printer, paper
> size, and orientation and closed the
> dialog, documentImageableArea points
> to an actual object and its properties
> are initialized.

I have my custom print dialog and need to get the PrintDocumentImageableArea of a given PrintQueue and PrintTicket! (I need the margin's I need to apply)

From what I can gather it is quite common for anything but the most basic applications to use their own custom print dialog. There must be a way to get to this information!?

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the GetPrintCapabilities() method of the PrintQueue and then query the PageImageableArea.

More information here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printcapabilities.pageimageablearea(v=VS.90).aspx

and here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552920.aspx

Comment: After some tests "PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth" and "PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight" have erratic values with some printers (values bigger than the page size).
I had to use the following code to get the right values :

    Size printSize = print.PrintTicket.PageOrientation.Value == PageOrientation.Landscape ?
    new Size(print.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize.Height.Value, print.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize.Width.Value)
    : new Size(print.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize.Width.Value, print.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize.Height.Value);